# Android Custom HorizontalScrollView child disappers when it is recreated

Tags: android, android-custom-view

In a project of mine, I have a custom `HorizontalScrollView` class that displays a line chart. It gets rid of all of the elements and then it adds a single `ImageView` as a child element. It works fine the first time, but if I were to change to other fragment and switch back to the fragment containing the line chart, the `ImageView` is not present, although the object is recreated exactly the same way as the first time. If I inspect it with the DDMS the `ImageView` is really not in the UI graph. Any ideas why?? I really need some help on that.

That is my code (from which I have omitted some irrelevant parts):

```
public class LineChartView extends HorizontalScrollView {
    // Private Constants ...

    // Private Fields...

    public LineChartView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public LineChartView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public LineChartView(Context context, float[] lineValues) {
        super(context);
        mLineValues = lineValues;
        init();
    }

    public LineChartView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, float[] lineValues) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mLineValues = lineValues;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // Setting densityMultiplier
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int pixelDensity = displayMetrics.densityDpi;
        mDensityMultiplier = pixelDensity / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;

        // Initalising Paints...

        initChildElements();
    }

    private void initChildElements() {
        removeAllViews();
        // Adding the image view to the visual graph
        mChartImage = new ImageView(getContext());
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams chartLayoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mChartImage.setLayoutParams(chartLayoutParams);
        addViewInLayout(mChartImage, 0, mChartImage.getLayoutParams(), true);
    }

    public void setLineValuesList(float[] lineValuesList) {
        if (lineValuesList == null) {
            mLineValues = new float[]{};
        } else {
            mLineValues = lineValuesList;
        }

        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        mChartImage.setImageDrawable(renderLineChart(h, 1.5f));  // Calculate the bitmap with the same height
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    private BitmapDrawable renderLineChart(int height, float scale) {
        if (height <= 0 || mLineValues.length == 0)
            return null;

            // Drawing logic... (not really relevant)


        return new BitmapDrawable(getContext().getResources(), resultBitmap);
    }

    private float calculateWidth(float distanceBetween) {
        int strokeCount = mLineValues.length - 1;
        return strokeCount * distanceBetween;
    }

    private float calculateDistanceToNextValue(float scale) {
        return BASE_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_POINTS * mDensityMultiplier * scale;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thus the `onLayout` member method of the class is never getting called (tried it several times)

Comment: Could you add your fragment code?

Comment: Well it's too much. But basically, I have an `ViewPager` that uses a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to display 3 fragments. I have the chart on the first fragment, but when I slide to the thrid fragment and the back to the first the `ImageView` is simply missing from the UI graph.

Comment: The `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is nothing special, I had simply overridden it to create instances of my three fragment classes.